# Public Class error when compiling with javac

Tags: java, class, compilation, javac, public

No matter what edits I make, I keep getting this output;

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin>javac JavaVersionDisplayApplet.java
JavaVersionDisplayApplet.java:4: error: error while writing JavaVersionDisplayAp
plet: JavaVersionDisplayApplet.class (Access is denied)
public class JavaVersionDisplayApplet extends Applet {
       ^
1 error
```

The code I'm using is for a JavaCheckVersion;

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JavaVersionDisplayApplet extends Applet { 
   private Label m_labVersionVendor; 

   public JavaVersionDisplayApplet()  { 
     Color colFrameBackground = Color.white;
     this.setBackground(colFrameBackground);
     m_labVersionVendor = new Label (" You are running Java Version: " +
                                    System.getProperty("java.version") +
                                    " from " + 
                                    System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
     this.add(m_labVersionVendor);
   }

}
```

Does anyone see anything wrong here?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have write permissions in the relevant place.

Comment: This is my first project in Java, so I'm not entirely sure how to modify that.

The line in question seems to be;
    public class JavaVersionDisplayApplet extends Applet {

Comment: Nothing to do with Java.  You just need to figure out why you can't write to whatever directory it's trying to generate the output in.

Comment: Generally you dont want to keep source files in the JDKs bin directory

Comment: You know what, its probably because I'm compiling from /jdk/bin/ as a workaround because javac wouldn't navigate to the original directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran CMD as admin, & moved the Java file to /Desktop/Java/ and was successful. Thanks everyone for helping me resolve this!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to your code, but rather to the fact that you are trying to compile it while your current directory is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin`. You probably don't have writing permissions in that directory. Since the action of compiling a class creates a `.class` file, the compiler cannot complete the compilation.

Change directory to some place where you are allowed to write, and compile again.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but that brings me to another problem. I'm compiling within jdk/bin/ because I would receive a "not found" error every time I'd try compiling from desktop/development folder/

Comment: @Autonomous Take a look at [Oracle's explanation of PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).